# How do you loop through an multidimenional array and delete key by name recursively in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to loop through an multidimensional arrary and the code is posted below. I want a function that I could pass the array to and a key that I could remove. It would be something like function removeItemFromMArray($YourArray, $RemoveKeyNamed); .

```
stdClass Object
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => New Balance - Variable Demo
                    [id] => 10393
                    [created_at] => 2013-07-24T14:35:21Z
                    [updated_at] => 2013-07-24T14:35:21Z
                    [type] => variable
                    [status] => publish
                    [downloadable] => 
                    [virtual] => 
                )


            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Mismo - Briefcase
                    [id] => 9619
                    [created_at] => 2013-06-10T13:18:17Z
                    [updated_at] => 2013-06-10T13:18:17Z
                    [type] => simple
                    [status] => publish
                    [downloadable] => 
                    [virtual] =>    
                )   
        )
)
```

I want to remove ID and return a new array with everything except for the ID.

Comment: the id is part of a object not an array

Comment: To further Ray's comment, there is no multidimensional array in the example shown; it is an object with a `products` property, with the latter being an (single-dimensional, associative) array of `stdClass` objects.

Comment: I wanted to keep it sure but it is multidimensional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array of objects

```
function removeItemFromMArray($YourArray, $RemoveKeyNamed) {
    foreach ($YourArray as $object) {
        unset($object->$RemoveKeyNamed);
    }
    return $YourArray;
}
$products = removeItemFromMArray($myArray->products, 'id');
```

OR

```
function removeItemFromMArray(&$YourArray, $RemoveKeyNamed) {
    foreach ($YourArray as $object) {
        unset($object->$RemoveKeyNamed);
    }
}
removeItemFromMArray($myArray->products, 'id');
```

Comment: We are almost the same.  You need to accept `$YourArray` as reference.

Comment: @cornelb there was no need to use *foreach-by-reference*, nor to wrap the *variable property* with curly braces. Edited for you.